# How to add a class to multiple elements?

Tags: javascript

Basically I like to add a new class to multiple elements with the same class name. Currently it adds a class only to the last one. I have tried using document.querySelectorAll but got no results. What I'm missing?

**HTML example**

```
<div class="model"></div>
<div class="model"></div>
<div class="model"></div>
```

**JS**

```
 _updateParagraph: function(settings, className) {
    var paragraph = document.querySelector('.' + className);
    paragraph.className = className;
    this._updateParagraphClasslist(settings, paragraph);
  },
```

**FULL JS**

```
App.Views.Preview = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: "#preview",
  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.update);
  },
  update: function() {
    var

      layout = [this.model.get("model")],
      format   = [this.model.get("size"), this.model.get("color-outside"), this.model.get("color")],
      color    = [this.model.get("color-inside")],
      material = [this.model.get('material')],
      lamination = [this.model.get('lamination')],
      logo = [this.model.get('embossing')];

    this._updateParagraph(layout, 'layout');
    this._updateParagraph(format, 'front');
    this._updateParagraph(format, 'back');
    this._updateParagraph(lamination, 'kit-front');
    this._updateParagraph(lamination, 'kit-back');
    this._updateParagraph(logo, 'embossing');
    this._updateParagraph(color, 'colorinner');
    this._updateParagraph(color, 'model');


  },
  _updateParagraph: function(settings, className) {
    var paragraph = document.querySelector('.' + className);
    paragraph.className = className;
    this._updateParagraphClasslist(settings, paragraph);
  },
  _updateParagraphClasslist: function(settings, paragraph) {
    _.each(settings, function(setting) {
      if (_.has(setting, "visual")) {
        paragraph.classList.add(setting.visual);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Why the native js DOM functions and the `jQuery` tag? ^^

Comment: @AmeyDeshpande http://jsfiddle.net/infous/8woaegx2/ it's maybe a clear example of the code you want. Check results in DOM.

Answer (score 36):

> I like to add a new class to multiple elements with the same class name

Using jQuery, you can target all element with class model along with `.addClass()` for adding class to all of them:

```
$('.model').addClass('newclass')
```

A pure javascript solution can be like following:

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.model');
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].classList.add('newclass');
}
```

Comment: Not me. Maybe he is looking for pure js version.

Comment: @CrimsonChin where is it?

Comment: @Jai sadly it would require a time machine to prove, the user has since removed the tag.

Comment: Thank you for the raw js verion of this.... Rarely anybody provides raw js solutions... ;)  +1.

Answer (score 6):

In 2022 (with IE out of the equation), you would do this (using `querySelectorAll`, `forEach`, and an arrow function):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.foo').forEach(el=>el.classList.add('bar'));
```

Comment: One liner neat solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for coming late, but I was thinking that using `getElementsByClassName` is probably more efficient :

```
var myDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('model');
[].forEach.call(myDivs, function(mySingleDiv) {
    mySingleDiv.classList.add('newclass');
});
```